# Circular reference while serializing EF model to Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, serialization, json.net

I know that are tons of questions related to this topic all over SO but none of them solved my problem.

I'm using MVC 5 with Entity Framework 6 and Newtonsoft.Json.

I have the usual scenario for this exception:

```
Service => Staff => Service
```

When I try to serialize a `service` object in my view, like this:

```
var arr = @Html.Raw(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Services));
```

I get the "`circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type...`" exception.

All the answers I found here say it is wasy to solve, I should just add

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
            .PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All;

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
        .ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
```

in my `Global.asax` file.

Well, I did, and it just doesn't work. I read a bunch of articles on MSDN an they all say the same thing. I don't know why, but it just doesn't work for me.

The only way I could make it work, was to create the whole serialization context in my controller:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize
};


var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
var msmStream = new MemoryStream();
var txtWriter = new StreamWriter(msmStream);
var writer = new JsonTextWriter(txtWriter) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
serializer.Serialize(writer, services);

var json = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msmStream.GetBuffer());
```

However, this is a terrible terrible solution, specially if I'm serializing a property from my view model on the fly in the view. It also defeats the whole purpose of a "global configuration".

Has anybody faced this problem?

Comment: Can you show your JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the DefaultSettings to new ones.

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize
};
```

Source

Comment: hi dear @vendettamit 
Where should I use this code?

Comment: use this code in  Application_Start() in global.asax

Answer (score 1):

The default serializer settings needs to be changed as follows.
In Global.aspx,

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    var jsonMediaTypeFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    jsonMediaTypeFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
    jsonMediaTypeFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
}
```

Comment: Please explain why the settings need to be changed

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. But I had to remove the line where you set the PreserveReferencesHandling, because it made the serialized JSON wrapped by reference handling object.

Answer (score 0):

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings` only affects Web API calls.  Since you are calling `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` directly, you either need to pass the settings directly to it as shown below or else set up the global default settings as shown in @vendettamit's answer.

```
var arr = @Html.Raw(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Services, new JsonSerializerSettings
                    { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. They should have made this very clear in the documentation, yet they only say "oh, just add this and that and it will work". I accepted vendettami's answer because it preserves the global configuration idea I need better.

Comment: Well they are probably assuming that if you're using Web API, you will make a controller method that returns the JSON and then call that via AJAX from your view.  It's unusual to serialize your model manually in the view itself.

Comment: I'm using mvc 5with web api, but I haven't started on the api yet. I have a strongly typed view where I work with razor, but depending on the user action, I mightneed to serialize parts of the model. It really is unusual