# web api returning no response but data is formed at return

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, postman

The `GetPlaces` method should return all users with their shares(homes), but I keep getting no response when I try to include the Shares.

The `API` gets called and it gets all data but when I try to return the data back,then I get no response.

It's not only that `API` call but every time I want to include another table from database, I get the same response. I am testing it with Postman

```
public class PlaceController : ControllerBase
{
    PlaceService _PlaceService;
    UserService _UserService;
    ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public PlaceController(PlaceService PlaceServicea, UserService _UserServicea, ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
        _PlaceService = PlaceServicea;
        _UserService = _UserServicea;
    }
    //get all places
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("all")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetPlaces()
    {
        var usersWithShares = await _db.Set<User>().Include(x => x.Shares).ToListAsync();

        return Ok(usersWithShares);
        // return Ok(await _PlaceService.GetAll());
    }
}
```

This is my entity User

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public long PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; internal set; }
    public ICollection<Place> Shares { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my Entity place

```
public class Place
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Rooms { get; set; }
    public int Garage { get; set; }
    public bool Garden { get; set; }
    public int Bathrooms { get; set; }
    public int Toilet { get; set; }
    public int Kitchen { get; set; }
    public int LivingRoom { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Adres Adres { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PlacePicture> PlacePictures { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my `ConfigureServices`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Homesharing"))
        );  
    // configure DI for application services
    services.AddScoped<UserService>();
    services.AddScoped<PlaceService>();
}
```

[See image for more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44SCu.png)

Comment: Please share `POSTMAN` result/error.

Comment: You probably get a circular reference error from the Json serializer.

Comment: Yes it was the circular reference error, I placed Jsonignore above ICollection and now it works great, is there alternative fix for that? btw how can i mark you're commend as answere

Comment: A (better) alternative is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37281026/861716). If you agree with that you may want to close your question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @DES PRO you can answer your own question after (I think) 48hrs. What you should probably think about doing is mapping your entities to a DTO class before returning from your API, exposing everything from your DB is not always a good idea and returning a DTO will mean your data structure can change without effecting the API contract.

Comment: @matt_lethargic Will I still need to add JsonIgnore on a ICollection property inside a DTO class?

Comment: It depends on how you get the data from the entity class and into your DTO class. I personally use Automapper a lot for this sort of thing and then set ignored fields in there. You don't have to include all the properties in your DTOs that are in your entity classes.