# Cant get related data with Linq/lambda. Public virtual class not filled out

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

My model:

```
     public partial class Books
     {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    public string Goal { get; set; }
    public int? Subjectid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Createdon { get; set; }
    //public string Subjectname { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Subjects> RelatedSubject { get; set; }

    public virtual Subjects Subject { get; set; }
```

My controller: (webapi)

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Books>>> GetBooks()
    {

        var Books = await _context.Books
            .Join(_context.Subjects,
            c => c.Subjectid,
            s => s.Id,
            (c, s) =>  new Subjects  {Id = s.Id, Name = s.Name,  })
            //(c, s) => new { subjectname = s.Subject, subjectid = s.Id })
            .ToListAsync();
        return Books;
        //return await _context.Books.ToListAsync();
    }
```

I get this error:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<myProject.Subjects>' to
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<myProject.Books>>'

WHen I call the api  I see the Subject is a empty property.

Why wont it get the Subject name from the linq/lambda?

**EDIT**

After some tips I tried this:

```
var Books = _context.Books.Include("Subjects.Name").ToListAsync();
```

> InvalidOperationException: Invalid include path: 'Subjects.Name' - couldn't find navigation for: 'Subjects'

Is it a relationship I should have added? I have database-first migrated.

Comment: Do you also get the error if you use anonymous type `(c, s) => new {Id = s.Id, Name = s.Name}`? What does your debugger saye about the types of Id and Name? Are these the same types as `Subjects.Id` and `Subjects.Name`?

Comment: Yes, it then says it dont work with `Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Books>>>`

Comment: should be `.Include("Subject")`, You load the `Subjects` object and you can access it like `books.Subject.Name`

Comment: I don't agree with `Include`. A `Select` should also work. It would work even faster, because the Include will transfer all columns of the table, inclusive the columns that you won't use. Only use Include if you plan to update the fetched data.

Comment: My, do some debugging: change for example the code without async await. What does it say? "It doesn't work" is not enough for us to detect your errors.

Comment: You were right. .Include("Subject")`` worked almost. The last part was that I had to do was to install Newtonsoft.json.

So now it works, in one way. But in the object Books it finds the related Subject. But then again in the object "Subject" it find all the related Books....So it is kind of a loop.


 I would have appreciated if you can point out some keyword for me to google to avoid that kind of looping.

Comment: @GerryMM88 check this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281026/circular-reference-while-serializing-ef-model-to-json#answer-39318848

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `virtual` keyword is only needed when using lazy-loading. Then the Property is loaded when first accessed (not when reading data from database).

When you want to load data from DB including some properties you may need to use `.Include()` [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

The code may look like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Books>>> GetBooks()
{
    var books = await _context.Books.Include(nameof(Books.Subject)).ToListAsync();
    return books;
}
```